# How C# StreamReader.readLine() distincts newline characters?

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

Assuming that I use tcp client and tcp server and transfer data via streamwriter/streamreader.
Client sends "HELLO WORLD ... some text ... \r\n" to server.

Server can read it in multiple ways:
"HELLO WORLD ... some text ... \r\n";
"HELLO" "WORLD ... some text ... \r\n";
"HELLO WORLD ... some text ... \r" "\n";

There are 3 newline chars "\r", \r\n", \n" depending on OS.

How would it know if something sent "\r" or "\r\n"?

If it tried to read one more byte it could hang forever because read func is blocking.
If it didn't try to to read one more byte it might left "\n" in stream which would be read by next function call leading to errors.

Comment: Where are comments??

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of [ReadLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_IO_StreamReader_ReadLine)

> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n"). The string that is returned does not contain the terminating carriage return or line feed. The returned value is null if the end of the input stream is reached.

So ReadLine would be allowed to return as soon as it has read *either* a "\n" or a "\r". It would need some extra code so that "\r\n" is not read as two separate lines, but that should be fairly easy to handle.

So you should not need to be worried about end line characters, streamreader should handle it correctly regardless of platform. And I would not worry about reading more from the stream than is available. Taking a look at the [source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs) shows that this seem to be handled by checking if there are characters available in the buffer.

Comment: The sane solution. Just read the documentation ;)

Comment: Uhm. I forgot that Microsoft is open-source now.