# StreamReader custom newline chars

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I don't understand the idea of distinction between \r\n and \r after reading the reference source code.
Could anyone explain it to me?
How does it works when networkstream got  only \r? Which property of networkstream it checks?

Comment: Could you explain what piece of code you are referring to specifically?

Comment: [From the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=net-6.0#remarks): *"A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately followed by a line feed ("\r\n"). The string that is returned does not contain the terminating carriage return or line feed. The returned value is null if the end of the input stream is reached."*

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question two days ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73020941/how-c-sharp-streamreader-readline-distincts-newline-characters

Comment: "immediately followed" what about network stream?

Comment: Where is the condition in ReadLine method that checks for networkstream for available data if it reads \r in one chunk and don't know if sender sends \n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\r` and the `\n` originate from the old typewriter.
If you "wrote" a `\r` the caret would go to the beginning of the sentence. If you started typing you would type over your sentence, so to mitigate this issue they introduced the `\n` which would turn the caret one line down.
So using `\r\n` actually means, set the caret to position 0, and move one line down.

Now this has been copied to computers, with roughly the same functionality.
In modern operating systems, the `\n` usually also resets your caret to 0 and the next line. So in essence, it actually behaves like a `\r\n`

More information about this can be found on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline